# XPath recursive

Tags: xml, xpath, recursion

A part of my xml-file:

```
<table>
    <row id="aant">
        <radio id="radaant">
            <omschrijving>test radio</omschrijving>
            <omschrijving>part 2</omschrijving>
            <table>
                <row id="testrow">
                    <radio id="testrad">
                        <omschrijving>test radio deeper</omschrijving>
                        <table/>
                    </radio>
                </row>
            </table>
        </radio>
    </row>
</table>
```

I would like to get the "omschrijving" from under the tag radio with id="radaant". Since "omschrijving" is also deeper in the child i always get "test radiopart 2test radio deeper" as result, but I just want "test radiopart 2".

I'm currently using xpath:
expr = xpath.compile("/table/row[@id='aant']/radio[@id='radaant']/omschrijving")

How can I change my xpath string to get only the "omschrijving" from the current node?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: your xpath selects the desired two `omschrijving` elements

Answer (score 2):

**You obviously are talking about another XML document or another XPath expression**.

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<table>
  <row id="aant">
    <radio id="radaant">
       <omschrijving>test radio</omschrijving>
       <omschrijving>part 2</omschrijving>
       <table>
          <row id="testrow">
            <radio id="testrad">
              <omschrijving>test radio deeper</omschrijving>
              <table/>
            </radio>
          </row>
       </table>
    </radio>
  </row>
</table>
```

**your XPath expression**:

```
/table/row[@id='aant']/radio[@id='radaant']/omschrijving
```

**selects exactly the wanted nodes**:

```
<omschrijving>test radio</omschrijving>
<omschrijving>part 2</omschrijving>
```

Comment: i was indeed wrong, but i fixed it now. Here i typed [@id='radaant'] but in my code i didn't fill it up. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

try expr = xpath.compile("/table/row[@id='aant']/radio[@id='radaant']/child::omschrijving")